# Cannot remap Window.NextDocumentWindow from Ctrl-F6 to Ctrl-PgDn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

As title says, I can't do it. When I do it, and I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGEDOWN</kbd>, it merely pages up/down in the source file.

Does anyone know why this is the case?